# Strange !doctype bug with parallax plugin 'skrollr'

Tags: html, doctype, parallax

Ok, so this has been causing me much pain and grief over the past two days and I finally narrowed the problem down but am in no way close to solving it.

I am building a parallax website using the [Skrollr](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/) plugin. The plugin will cease to function in my document as soon as there is a `<!doctype html>` present.

I have created a new simple example and it's still producing the same bug.

The strange thing is that on their own website they are declaring the same `<!doctype html>` as I am but it works there.

**My Code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Document</title>
<style>

    .section1{
        height:1000px;
        background:gray;
    }

    .section1 img {
        width:2000px;
        height:1000px;
    }

    .section2{
        width:2000px;
        height:1000px;
        background:url('background2.jpg');
        position: absolute;
    }

    .section3{
        width:2000px;
        height:1000px;
        background:url('background3.jpg');
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<section class="section1">
    <div style="position:absolute; background:url('background1.jpg') no-repeat; width:100%; height:1000px; background-size:cover;" data-0="top:0;" data-1200="top:350px;"></div>
</section>
<section class="section2"></section>
<section class="section3"></section>

<script src="skrollr.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var s = skrollr.init({
            edgeStrategy: 'set',
            easing: {
                WTF: Math.random,
                inverted: function(p) {
                    return 1-p;
                }
            }
        });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in what browser is it failing to work? if it's IE add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> to your head so that IE knows to render properly (not in quirks mode)

Comment: Sorry, It's not working in any browser. Im developing in Chrome at the moment.

Comment: You should elaborate on "not working" do you see any errors in the developer console (F12)? Is it functioning at all or completely dead?

Comment: Completely dead with no errors in the console. It's as if the plugin isn't included in the site.

Comment: @LastCoder Actually. It does move the image but not in one motion. If I scroll down and up really quickly I can see it 'snap' back to where it was. But it's an instant movement not an animation.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder that I've posted the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify a unit for the value of the `top` property of the first keyframe.

Yours: `data-0="top:0;"`
Correct: `data-0="top:0px;"`

When omitting the `DOCTYPE`, the browser becomes less strict and assumes you mean pixels when you set `top` to `100` or similar.

See also: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#limitations

> All numeric values have to have the same unit. It's not possible to animate from 0% to 100px. skrollr won't complain, but results are undefined.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to figure this out last night. All works like a dream now. Great work on the plugin btw. It's by far the best parallax plugin out there.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment, but I have a question. Can you post some HTML with your CSS and JS so we can get a better look.

As a note, something IS different from your code to theirs, if it was not, then logically, yours should work.

Did you check your CSS/JS against theirs and make sure something was not messed up?

Comment: Yeah, I even hot linked to their script! I really cannot understand why this doesn't work. So my project is built on laravel with frontend boilerplate and grunt etc. There were many variables that could have been a factor. So I started again and created 1 index.html (in my op) which works perfect if i remove the doctype.

Comment: By remove it, do you mean you don't declare it at all? Or do you mean you set it to something else?

Comment: Don't declare it at all. If I declare any doctype it breaks. I've seen other sites using this plugin and they are using doctype fine.

Comment: My first thought was that IE is rendering Quirks mode because of there not being a doctype declaration, but you said you're using chrome for testing, right? I'll do some research with that in mind and get back to you.