# Issue with skrollr and declaring doctype

Tags: skrollr

I'm experiencing a weird issue with skrollr - I followed the steps at https://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/ using just two slides - a background image with a header that fades and then page content. If I have !doctype set, the first slide doesn't go full-height - but works if I just use

I've seen [Strange !doctype bug with parallax plugin 'skrollr'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860311/strange-doctype-bug-with-parallax-plugin-skrollr), but I can't see anywhere where I'm defining an ambiguous height.

The site I'm working on is http://he.dev.binaryitsystems.com/

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed up by using the more up to date examples in the github repo.